# Markov chain hitting probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

This was a task in an exam I had in July and I wuld like to know how to solve this task.

Given: Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with state space $I=\{0,1,\ldots\}$, initial distribution $\lambda=\delta_0$ and transition probabilities $$p_{00}=1/3,\ p_{01}=2/3,\ p_{i,i-1}=1/3,\ p_{i,i+1}=2/3,\ i\ge1$$ and all other transition probabilities equal $0$.

Let $H=\inf\{n\ge 0: X_n=0\}$ be the hitting time for the state $0$ and $h_i=\mathbb P_i[H<\infty]$ the according hitting probability. Using the weak markov-property we get a (infinite) system of linear equations.

Find this system of equations and show that its general solution is

$$x_i=-1+2^{1-i}+\xi(2-2^{1-i}),i\ge0, \xi \in \mathbb R$$

Which choice of $\xi$ yiels the hitting probabilities $(h_i:i\in I)$?

Theory:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIto4.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQO7.png)

Comment: You know the value of $h_0$ so you can solve the second part of the question without knowing the answer to the first part.

Comment: If you let $D_i$ be the event that we hit 0, given we start in state $i$, you can use the law of total probability $$h_i = P[D_i] = P[D_i|something]P[something] + P[D_i|somethingelse]P[somethingelse]$$

Comment: $$h_1 = -1 + 2^{1-1} + \xi(2-2^{1-1}) =\implies h_1=0 $$ so something is wrong here...